# How do I include a maven jar project to a maven war project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, war, pom.xml

I have an eclipse java/jar project that used to statically link to other jar files. I remade this project into a maven project (Listing 1) so I could remove these static jar files and let maven resolve them.
And I have another war web application that I also transformed another project MyWarProject that used to have a dependency on MyJarProject to maven. And added MyJarProject as a dependency (Listing 2).

This the upper section pom.xml for my jar project

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MyJarProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyJarProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


  <build>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <goals>
             <goal>jar</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

    <dependencies>......
```

This is the full listing pom.xml for the war project that depends on the jar file

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MyWarProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyWarProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>




    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>MyJarProject</groupId>
            <artifactId>MyJarProject</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

     <build>
    <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
      <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <directory>src</directory>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </resource>
      </resources>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>

  </project>
```

The first jar projects builds fine after a maven clean install. However the war project displays this error message. Those missing classes like ItemsDAO are supposed to be resolved from the jar project.
And no jar file is actually copied to the WEB-INF folder. Please help!

```
INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ MyWarProject ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ MyWarProject ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 41 source files to C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\target\classes
[INFO] Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[INFO] Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\src\com\rd\test\MyWarProject\utility\MegaItemProcessCodeType.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/iaddou/workspace1/MyWarProject/src/com/rd/test/MyWarProject/utility/WebServicesLogger.java:[3,30] C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\src\com\rd\test\MyWarProject\utility\WebServicesLogger.java:3: package com.rd.test.common does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/iaddou/workspace1/MyWarProject/src/com/rd/test/MyWarProject/utility/WebServicesLogger.java:[15,32] C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\src\com\rd\test\MyWarProject\utility\WebServicesLogger.java:15: package com.documentum.fc.client does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/iaddou/workspace1/MyWarProject/src/com/rd/test/MyWarProject/utility/WebServicesLogger.java:[216,17] C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\src\com\rd\test\MyWarProject\utility\WebServicesLogger.java:216: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class IDfSession
location: class com.rd.test.MyWarProject.utility.WebServicesLogger
[ERROR] /C:/Users/iaddou/workspace1/MyWarProject/src/com/rd/test/MyWarProject/MegaItemsImpl.java:[15,30] C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\src\com\rd\test\MyWarProject\MegaItemsImpl.java:15: package com.rd.test.common does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/iaddou/workspace1/MyWarProject/src/com/rd/test/MyWarProject/MegaItemsImpl.java:[16,30] C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\src\com\rd\test\MyWarProject\MegaItemsImpl.java:16: package com.rd.test.common does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/iaddou/workspace1/MyWarProject/src/com/rd/test/MyWarProject/MegaItemsImpl.java:[17,35] C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\src\com\rd\test\MyWarProject\MegaItemsImpl.java:17: package com.rd.test.common.data does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/iaddou/workspace1/MyWarProject/src/com/rd/test/MyWarProject/MegaItemsImpl.java:[42,13] C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\src\com\rd\test\MyWarProject\MegaItemsImpl.java:42: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ItemsDAO
location: class com.rd.test.MyWarProject.MegaItemsImpl
[ERROR] /C:/Users/iaddou/workspace1/MyWarProject/src/com/rd/test/MyWarProject/MegaItemVersionHistoryImpl.java:[11,30] C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\src\com\rd\test\MyWarProject\MegaItemVersionHistoryImpl.java:11: package com.rd.test.common does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/iaddou/workspace1/MyWarProject/src/com/rd/test/MyWarProject/MegaItemVersionHistoryImpl.java:[12,30] C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\src\com\rd\test\MyWarProject\MegaItemVersionHistoryImpl.java:12: package com.rd.test.common does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/iaddou/workspace1/MyWarProject/src/com/rd/test/MyWarProject/MegaItemVersionHistoryImpl.java:[13,35] C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\src\com\rd\test\MyWarProject\MegaItemVersionHistoryImpl.java:13: package com.rd.test.common.data does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/iaddou/workspace1/MyWarProject/src/com/rd/test/MyWarProject/MegaItemVersionHistoryImpl.java:[40,17] C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\src\com\rd\test\MyWarProject\MegaItemVersionHistoryImpl.java:40: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class VersionHistoryDAO
location: class com.rd.test.MyWarProject.MegaItemVersionHistoryImpl
[ERROR] /C:/Users/iaddou/workspace1/MyWarProject/src/com/rd/test/MyWarProject/MegaItemDetailImpl.java:[12,30] C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\src\com\rd\test\MyWarProject\MegaItemDetailImpl.java:12: package com.rd.test.common does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/iaddou/workspace1/MyWarProject/src/com/rd/test/MyWarProject/MegaItemDetailImpl.java:[13,30] C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\src\com\rd\test\MyWarProject\MegaItemDetailImpl.java:13: package com.rd.test.common does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/iaddou/workspace1/MyWarProject/src/com/rd/test/MyWarProject/MegaItemDetailImpl.java:[14,35] C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\src\com\rd\test\MyWarProject\MegaItemDetailImpl.java:14: package com.rd.test.common.data does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/iaddou/workspace1/MyWarProject/src/com/rd/test/MyWarProject/MegaItemDetailImpl.java:[39,17] C:\Users\iaddou\workspace1\MyWarProject\src\com\rd\test\MyWarProject\MegaItemDetailImpl.java:39: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ItemDAO
```

Comment: Can you please post the output with debug enabled? `mvn clean install -X`

Comment: First the explicit binding of maven-jar-plugin in your jar project is superfluous cause it's handled by the life cycle. Furthermore changing the default directory layout is a bad idea...keep the conventions...Furthermore have you done a `mvn install` on the jar project and afterwards build the war project ? This sounds like a case for a multi module build...

Comment: Can you verify that after mvn clean install on your jar project, your jar is build in your local repostitory in .m2 folder in your home directory (or in your user directory on windows?) Also you could you please verify contents of your jar file?

Comment: Yes it is created in my .m2